# Effective element movement on keystroke in React

Tags: reactjs, position, keystroke

I'm programming movement of element by left and right arrow keys in React. Unfortunaltely, my code is no effective. Render method is called a lot of time when value becomes far from initial value - 50 (we can see in console.log). So probably no the best way. Any idea how make it work?

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

function App () {
  const [elementPosition, setElementPosition] = useState(50)
  console.log(elementPosition)
  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener('keydown', keyPress)
  })

  const keyPress = (e) => {
    switch (e.which) {
      case 37: {
        // left
        setElementPosition(elementPosition - 1)
        break
      }
      case 39: {
        // right
        setElementPosition(elementPosition + 1)
        break
      }
      default:
    }
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className='element' style={{left: elementPosition + '%', width:'10px', height: '10px', position: 'absolute', backgroundColor: 'red'}} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create the event listener once, and remove the event once component is unmounted. Also update the state using callback function, that way you can get the current state value:

```
 useEffect(() => {
    document.addEventListener('keydown', keyPress);
      return ()=> {
        document.removeEventListener('keydown', keyPress);
      }
 }, []);
    
 const keyPress = (e) => {
    switch (e.which) {
      case 37: {
        // left
        setElementPosition((elementPosition)=> elementPosition - 1)
        break
      }
      case 39: {
        // right
        setElementPosition((elementPosition)=> elementPosition + 1)
        break
      }
      default:
    }
  }
```